# Бинарное дерево

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста. Требуется написать программу с бинарным деревом.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct bin_node         //--------------одна из вершин    
{
    int data;
    bin_node *left;
    bin_node *right;
};

struct bin_tree         // -----само дерево  
{
    bin_node *root;     // вершина  
    int count;          //количество вершин      
};

int all[13];

//-----------прототипы функций------------------------  
void vvod();
struct bin_tree *bin_create();
int bin_insert(struct bin_tree *mytree, int);
void write_in_file(bin_node * node, ofstream &);

//-------------------------------------
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, " ");
    ofstream o;
    vvod();
    int all[13];
    struct bin_tree *mytree = bin_create(); // присвоение дереву выделенной под него памяти
    struct bin_node *node;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        bin_insert((bin_tree *) mytree, all[i]);
    }
    node = mytree->root;
    printf("\n после прохода по дереву \n");
    write_in_file(node, o);
    o.close();
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//-------------создание дерева---------------------------  
struct bin_tree *bin_create()
{
    struct bin_tree *mytree = (bin_tree *) malloc(sizeof *mytree);
    if (mytree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else {
        mytree->root = NULL;    //пустой корень  
        mytree->count = 0;  // нуль вершин    
    }
};

//--------------поиск вершины------------------------------------
int bin_search(const struct bin_tree *mytree, int item)
{
    const struct bin_node *node;
    assert(mytree != NULL); //если дерево существует  
    node = mytree->root;
    for (;;) {
        if (node == NULL)
            return 0;
        if (item == node->data) // если искомое значение совпадает с data, 
            return 1;   // возвращаем 1
        if (item > node->data)
            node = node->right; //если больше, шагаем в правый узел  
        else if (item < node->data)
            node = node->left;
    }
}

//--------------------вставка в узел----------------------------------
int bin_insert(struct bin_tree *mytree, int item)
{
    bin_node *node;     // указатель на значение Bin_node
    bin_node **nee;     // указатель на адрес bin_node  
    assert(mytree != NULL);
    nee = &mytree->root;    //пишем адрес в nee
    node = mytree->root;
    for (;;)        // цикл добавления 
    {
        if (node == NULL) {

            *nee = (bin_node *) malloc(sizeof *node);
            node = *nee;
            if (node != NULL) {
                node->data = item;
                node->left = NULL;
                node->right = NULL;
                mytree->count++;
                return 1;
            } else
                return 0;

        } else if (item == node->data)
            return 2;
        else if (item > node->data) {
            nee = &node->right;
            node = node->right;
        } else if (item < node->data) {
            nee = &node->left;
            node = node->left;
        }

    }
}

void vvod()
{
    printf("...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &all[i]);
    }
    printf("\näî îáõîäà: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        printf("%d ", all[i]);
    }
}

void write_in_file(bin_node * node, ofstream & o)
{
    o.open("file.txt");
    if (node != NULL)   // åñëè äåðåâî íå ïóñòî
    {
        write_in_file(node->right, o);  
        o << node->data << " "; // ïèøåì â ôàéë
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        write_in_file(node->left, o);
    }
}
```

Программа компилируется, но выдаёт ошибку. Не могу найти её.... ошибка где-то в bin_insert

Comment: ofstream - класс файловых потоков, предназначенных для записи в файл. Если Вам это неизвестно, срочно садитесь за учебник, а то толку от ответов будет NULL.

Comment: Прототип? Не такая ли строчка нужна:

void write_in_file (bin_node *, ofstream &);

Comment: Заголовочный файл fstream вставлен?

Comment: Отлично. В начале файла есть запись #include <fstream>  ?

Comment: Для решения указанных проблем хорошо бы увидеть весь текст программы.

Comment: я отредактировала вопрос, добавив, как вы попросили, текст программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вижу ошибку

```
void write_in_file (bin_node *node, ofstream &);
```

Надо

```
void write_in_file ( struct bin_node *node, ofstream &);
```

Далее. В функции

```
struct bin_tree *bin_create()
```

не возвращается результат.

Comment: да, заработало.
Спасибо Вам огромнейшее!!!!! и прошу прощения за подобное бепокойство. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, но я вижу еще кучу ошибок. Сейчас не могу все описать подробно. Надо учиться, и учиться серьезно.

Comment: я понимаю. только к сожалению, приходится в основном самой, т.к. в университете дают на удивление мало
ладно, не буду флудить

Comment: Я вообще по образованию биолог. А в каких обстоятельствах учил С++ - умолчую